how can i show state label in react google geo chart in US region
<Chart
      chartEvents={[
        {
          eventName: "select",
          callback: ({ chartWrapper }) => {
            const chart = chartWrapper.getChart();
            const selection = chart.getSelection();
            if (selection.length === 0) return;
            const region = data[selection[0].row + 1];
            console.log("Selected : " + region);
          },
        },
      ]}
      chartType="GeoChart"
      options={{
        region: "US",
        displayMode: "regions",
        backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
        resolution: "provinces",
        colors: ["#BDDBF7", "#6287AA", "#6287AA"],
      }}
      mapProperties={{
        tooltip: { isHtml: true },
      }}
      width="100%"
      height="400px"
      rootProps={{ "data-testid": "1" }}
      data={[[
      ["TX", "Texas", 345],
      ["UT", "Utah", 68],
      ["WY", "Wyoming", 45],
    ]]}
/>

I want to show state label in this map, i am using react google geo chart:

I have tried by giving displayMode regions and resolution: "provinces",
but still not showing state label; I have to show label in this map.

include latitude and longitude
Use displayMode: "markers"
 const data = [
  ["Latitude", "Longitude", "State", "Value"],
  [31.9686, -99.9018, "Texas", 345],
  [39.3200, -111.0937, "Utah", 68],
  [43.0759, -107.2903, "Wyoming", 45]
];



    const options = {
  region: "US",
  displayMode: "markers",
  backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
  resolution: "provinces",
  colors: ["#BDDBF7", "#6287AA", "#6287AA"],
  sizeAxis: { minValue: 0, maxSize: 10 },
  legend: "none"
};
    const chartEvents = [
  {
    eventName: "select",
    callback: ({ chartWrapper }) => {
      const chart = chartWrapper.getChart();
      const selection = chart.getSelection();
      if (selection.length === 0) return;
      const region = data[selection[0].row + 1];
      console.log("Selected : " + region[2]);
    }
  }
];

const GeoChart = () => (
  <Chart
    chartEvents={chartEvents}
    chartType="GeoChart"
    options={options}
    data={data}
    width="100%"
    height="400px"
    rootProps={{ "data-testid": "1" }}
  />
);


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

as i have written include or try to give your project the latitude and longitude values
